# how to assign an ip address to a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have assigned ip address to a variable in the following way.

```
  set /A myvar = 10.0.0.1
  echo %myvar%
```

but it is giving the result as only 10 not entire ip address.. so can some give the solution for it

Comment: You should try to accept answers that was helpfull to your questions. Thats the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
set myvar=10.0.0.1 
echo %myvar%
```

The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
is a numerical expression that is evaluated.  The expression evaluator
Note: no spaces around "=" sign

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `/A`, its for numerical expressions

```
set myvar=10.0.0.1
echo %myvar%
//10.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `/A`, then it will work.

```
C:\>help set
[...]
The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
is a numerical expression that is evaluated.
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put quotation marks around the ip address?  "10.0.0.1"